# Enable CORS for getting an inline SVG by URL

Tags: headers, http, svg

TLDR; Is there a way I can enable CORS for SVGs in my WordPress back-end, so I can get them through a http request to a different domain? Ideally without having to touch `.htaccess`?

## What I'm aiming for

I am building a headless WordPress/React site. I would like to have my SVGs, uploaded to WP back-end, inlined into my front-end code (so I can access their DOM).

I have URL to the SVG and `react-inlinesvg` library allows me to inline it. I am getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error however. `react-inlinesvg` makes the actual http request through `httpplease`library.

## What I've tried

At first, I had to enable upload of SVGs to the admin.

```
add_filter('upload_mimes', function($mimes) {
    return array_replace($mimes, [
        'svg' => 'image/svg+xml',
        'svgz' => 'image/svg+xml'
    ]);
});
```

I've found those filters as well, but I don't think they are being fired if the file is requested via http:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function($wp) {
    remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
    add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        return $value;
    });
});

add_filter('wp_headers', function($headers) {
    $headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
    return $headers;
});
```

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm surprised you're serving SVGs though the REST API. Aren't they static content from /wp-content/uploads ?

Answer (score 0):

By using custom `rewrite_url`, I was able to hijack the request and set its CORS-friendly headers.

```
class Cors_Media {

    const QUERY_VAR = 'cors_media_id';

    public function init() {
        add_action('init', [$this, 'add_rewrite_rule']);
        add_filter('query_vars', [$this, 'query_vars']);
        add_action('template_redirect', [$this, 'template_redirect']);
    }

    public function query_vars(array $qs) {
        $qs[] = 'cors_media_id';
        return $qs;
    }

    public function add_rewrite_rule() {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^cors_media_id/([0-9]+)/?',
            'index.php?cors_media_id=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );
    }

    public function template_redirect() {
        $att_id = get_query_var('cors_media_id');
        if (empty($att_id)) { return; }
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url($att_id);
        if ($url) {
            $this->show_file($url);
        }
        exit;
    }

    protected function show_file($url) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        echo file_get_contents($url);
        exit;
    }

}

$obj = new Cors_Media;
$obj->init();
```